# InputMask Range from 0 to 254

Tags: javascript, jquery, input-mask

I have tried various other Stackoverflow [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26649788/range-0-100-using-jquery-inputmask-plugin) and cannot get it to work.  I need an input mask that validates the input is from 0 to 254.

**MY CURRENT ATTEMPT:**
This is from the example & fails utterly...

```
dictionary.elements.txtGlobalAddress.inputmask('Regex', { regex: "^[0-9][0-9][0-9]?$|^254$" });
```

[image]

Comment: `^([0-9]|[1-8][0-9]|9[0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-4])$` will match numbers from 0 to 254.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a regex that will match a whole number from 0 to 254.

`^([0-9]|[1-8][0-9]|9[0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-4])$`

You can test it here:

[Regex test](https://regex101.com/r/O2zYC3/1)

Remember that regular expresions deals with text and trying to match a number range could be hard if you don't understand them. [Here's more info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html) about it so you can learn how the regex above works.